# .val() заменяет весь текст в инпуте, а нужно прибавить

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".inv_item").click(function(event){
   $(".set_input").val($(this).children("p").html() + "/");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class=inv_item>Добавить<p> этот текст</button>
<input value="тут уже что-то есть" class=set_input>
```

Собственно в данном коде, при клике на .inv_item, заносится текст в инпут с классом .set_input. Но проблема в том, что при каждом нажатии текст в инпуте заменяется на новый, а мне нужно, чтобы старый текст не удалялся и новый добавлялся после него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.set_input').val($('.set_input').val() + $(this).children("p").html() + "/");
```

Думаю так.

Comment: $('.set_input').html() ???

Comment: К сожалению не сработало.

Comment: @BimBam, попробуй с .val() исправленную. Если и не работает, то суть сама в том, чтобы получать предыдущее значение и в конец конкатенировать что нужно, и получившееся устанавливать.

Comment: Да. Сработало. Грац.

Comment: @BimBam отметьте ответ как верный, если он ответил на Ваш вопрос